# WPF C# ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I am currently developing a clickonce application and we are starting testing in the clients machines. Actually, I have 10 clients, in 3 of them I'm getting the following error :

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///Y:/PainelGerencial/publish/x86/PainelPendencias.application
    Application url         : file:///Y:/PainelGerencial/publish/x86/Application%20Files/PainelPendencias_1_0_0_24/PainelPendencias.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : PainelPendencias.application, Version=1.0.0.24, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1050266e357c1d23, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : PainelPendencias.exe, Version=1.0.0.24, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1050266e357c1d23, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of Y:\PainelGerencial\publish\x86\PainelPendencias.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Activation failed.
        + Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:06] : Activation of Y:\PainelGerencial\publish\x86\PainelPendencias.application has started.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:06] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:06] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:07] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:09] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:09] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:10] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:10] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:11] : Installation of application has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [20/10/2016 16:37:11] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Activation)
        - Activation failed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.UnauthorizedAccessException
        - Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    * Transaction at [20/10/2016 16:37:11]
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: CJ3D5GY9.MXQ.application
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: PainelPendencias.exe.manifest
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: PainelPendencias.exe.config
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: PainelPendencias.exe.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: PainelPendencias.exe
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - Manifest: De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.dll.genman
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
            - Status: Installed
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - File: De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.dll
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationPinDeployment
            - Status: Pinned
            - HRESULT: 0x0
            - AppId: file:///Y:/PainelGerencial/publish/x86/PainelPendencias.application#PainelPendencias.application, Version=1.0.0.24, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1050266e357c1d23, processorArchitecture=x86
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
            - HRESULT: 0x0

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I highly recommend looking into [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) it's a significant improvement over click-once - much more control, easier to debug, and well maintained.

Comment: I´d rather a solution with no third part app.